# How to test apicontroller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I try to write some unit tests for my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public Answer RegistrationSocial([FromBody] RegistrationSocialRequest newUser)
{
    var answer = new Answer();
    try
    {
        userProvider.RegistrationSocial(newUser.Email, 
                                        newUser.PhoneNumber,
                                        newUser.SocialProviderId,
                                        newUser.SocialProvider, 
                                        UserIP);
        answer.Result = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        answer.Result = 2;
        answer.Description = "Server error";
    }
    return answer;
}

private string UserIP
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress; }
}
```

RegistrationSocialRequest is just a POCO object which is needed for Model Binding. This method return json and I want to track its change, just to be sure that clients can work with it. For testing I use Moq and MSTest. Here is the test method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsJsonOkRegistrationSocial()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IUserProvider> mock = new Mock<IUserProvider>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.RegistrationSocial("lincoln@usa.gov", 
                                         "123", 
                                         "0987654321",
                                          1, 
                                          "192.0.0.1"));

    UserController controller = new UserController(mock.Object);
    Answer answerOk = new Answer
    {
        Result = 0,
        Caption = "Ok",
        Description = null,
        Data = null
    };

    //Action
    var answer = controller.RegistrationSocial(new RegistrationSocialRequest
    {
        SocialProvider = 1,
        Email = "lincoln@usa.gov",
        PhoneNumber = "123",
        SocialProviderId = "0987654321"
    });

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answerOk),
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answer));
}
```

But method thrown exception, because UserIP is null, and I can`t undestand why. I am new in unit testing, maybe this all could be done in easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress isn't set as you expect when you run the code outside the web environment, when you run your unit test.

On solution is to create an 'IHttpContextService' with a method 'GetUserIP'. In this way you could call this service in the UserIP-property and when testing you could mock the interface.

Comment: Maybe some over engineering, but this solution is work. Thank you.